# How do I create this specific bake map?

Tags: rendering, texture-baking, baking, shadows

I had gotten a bake from a friend which I absolutely love!

I've searched around I don't even know the name of the bake to even find the correct tutorial. It's not a normal shadow/AO map. It has like a metallic grey shading with more of a 3d effect. I'm attaching images of the bakes with the hope that someone knows the name of the bake and can tell me how to achieve it on my own.

Here's some examples:
[1](https://gyazo.com/33e1922702355738468281d8d4ae3053)
[2](https://gyazo.com/c33b2ef2805f6cf8aa4ad84397eea036)
[3](https://gyazo.com/a301b6f6f145156a729eef31805fbf04)

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this Please edit your question and add the images so they show as part of your post.

Answer (score 2):

If you give your object a *Metallic* value of 1 with a *Roughness* of 0.5 then *Bake Type > Glossy*, you'll have this kind of result:

[image]